# Android Dialog memory leak on app exit

Tags: android, memory-leaks, dialog

I have noticed that dialogs (not sure about DialogFragments) will report a memory leak when you put in the app in the background and then dismiss it while in the background.  Of course the way to handle this is to clean it up in onPause so its not really an issue, but my question is:

What are the impact of memory leaks if they are occurring as the app is exiting?  It is talked about here https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html under "Switching Apps"
but the way it is worded leaves me to think maybe it is just referring to apps put in the background, not apps being closed hence the reason it is under Switching Apps.

Any clarification or pointing to additional resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks